# How did the Seder Plate look according Jacob ben Asher?

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada

Interested in the question of how the Seder Plate looked like in Jacob ben Asher. More precisely, even the question of how he arranged the matzo. I know that Rema and the Vilna Gaon placed the matzo on the plate, not under it. Also interesting is the opinion of such sages as Rosh and Rashi.

Comment: Why are you interested in the Tur specifically?

Comment: Hi @danklbaruri welcome to Mi Yodeya! From where do you assume he did it differently?

Comment: @Double AA, I am interested in the opinion of such a significant halakhic authority at one time.

Comment: @Dov there are multiple opinions so it's trivial to conclude he did it differently from some.

Comment: @Dov, I suspect that the opinion of Jacob ben Asher is close to that of Rema, at least in the location of the matzo.